# How to get ride of `com.pentaho.commons.dsc.f: license missing, invalid, or expired?`

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle

I made a `Transform` to send `JMS Produce` to `ActiveMQ`.

but during executing the transform via my Java Client Application including `PDI` Jars.

I faced this Error :

```
2014/08/10 13:06:54 - ACTIVEMQ - Dispatching started for transformation [ACTIVEM
Q]
Exception in thread "Thread-8" com.pentaho.commons.dsc.f: license missing, inval
id, or expired
        at com.pentaho.commons.dsc.j.a(SourceFile:92)
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.jms.f.<init>(SourceFile:61)
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.jms.JmsOutputMeta.getStep(SourceFile:58)
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans.prepareExecution(Trans.java:891)
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans.execute(Trans.java:604)
```

I tried to use the license file that installed with `Pentaho` called `.installedLicenses.xml` but no effect!

I know that `Pentaho` is under `Full Free License`, so what's the problem and what do I do?

Comment: It looks like your trail licence expired. What version of Penthao you are using? CE (downloaded from sourceforge, jenkins, ect) or EE downloaded from Pentaho site after typing your contact informations?

Comment: Hello, I downloaded Pentaho CE from Pentaho.com

Comment: I highly doubt that you have downloaded CE from pentaho :-) did you installed it via installation wizard or it's just zip file?

Comment: @StevanPopov Hello Steven, you are right, of course i used `Pentaho CE` but i copied plugin called `JMS` from `plugins` folder inside the version `.exe` that i installed from pentaho website. because i didn't find this plugin inside `Pentaho CE`, so where to find it ?

Comment: Actually from this `Jar` `pentaho-ee-dsc-core-5.1.0.0-752.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the plugin you're trying to use is an Enterprise Edition plugin and requires a valid license to run.

When you download the trial version you get a 30 day license.

Comment: Thank you i know this now. Do you know how much the license of `Pentaho EE` ? and is it monthly or one time

Comment: I think the most common is a yearly license, but you can get in touch with the sales rep for your region. You can also try Stevan's suggestion and find/develop an Open Source alternative for that plugin

Answer (score 1):

JMS plugin is EE licenced.

There could be solution for you.

First, check [this](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?59797-JMS-Plugin). Try to contact plugin creator if he want to share it.

He had also shared his code. If you are familiar with Java, you would probably be in position to create plugin by yourself and maybe to share it with others. (note - he was designing for older version).

It might be painful but even a paying someone (local guy, employee, freelancing sites, wasting your time on this), can be cheaper than buying EE solution **because of one plugin** (if you need other options it's off the topic right now) and it would be a great addition to pentaho community.